# How to get the rejection region and type II error probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00356, in the section 5.2
the author does the independent test on Section 5. Assume that $\pi$ is the coupling of probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $[0,1]$. The hypothesis test for independence is that
$$
H_0: \pi=\mu\times \nu \, , H_a: \pi\neq \mu\times \nu
$$
The test statistic is $W(\hat{\pi}^N)$.

[image]

In my understanding, this Corollary says that
under $H_0$ holds, we reject the $H_0$ if
$$
W(\hat{\pi}^N)>C(\nu)(C_N+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha))
$$

In the paper, the author upper bound the estimator by an asymptotic normal  random variable as in the proof in P11, that is
$$
W(\hat{\pi}^N)\le C(\nu)T_N(\pi)
$$
where under $H_0$ holds, $\sqrt{N}(T_N(\pi)-C_N)/\sigma\to N(0,1)$ in Lemma A.1 (page 25).

My question is that

Q1: How to get this rejection region? It seems that we need to upper bound
$$
P(W(\hat{\pi}^N)>C(\nu)(C_N+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha))|H_0 true)\le \alpha
$$
for significance level $\alpha$.

Q2: In the simulation, for two data sets $X\sim Unif[0,1]$ and $Y=0.2X$ (they are dependent), why
$$
P(\text{type II error})=P(\text{accept} H_0|H_0 \text{false})=P(W(\hat{\pi}^N)>>C(\nu)(C_N+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha))?
$$
It seems this Corollary holds as $H_0$ is true. But here our data samples are not independent ($H_0$ is wrong).

Comment: Where do you get the formula in your question? It doesn't seem to be in the article. It seems to me that the inequality should be the other way around, since you're accepting $H_0$. Also, the probability should be measured w.r.t. an alternative hypothesis. Which one do you pick?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Sorry. I add more details. Can you take a look?